# Swift- Get current date with different timezones to compare between times

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I've been looking for this but couldnt found a solution that corresponds correctly with my needs. I need to get a Date of type NSDate, not a String, which includes the current time of a specific timezone to later compare it to see if the time is between a range.

For example I need to see if a store is open. I am at EST timezone and it's 11:30 pm so I see the schedule of a store that closes at 11 but the store is at PST which means that now it's 10pm in that zone and stills open. So I need to change my timezone to the store timezone to show a flag if it is open or closed right now.

This is an example of what I tried:

```
guard let tz = model?.timeZone else {return "EST"};    
let tz = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: timeZone);
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
let dateString = df.string(from:Date()); //time is correct
let date = df.date(from: dateString); //ignore timeZone and transform to a different date.
```

But when I convert the String that do contains the time with the timezone set correctly and parse it back to Date type it just ignore the timeZone and displays a different time. 
I think I will have to do something like get the difference between times and add to the current time but Im not really sure of how to get that done. Because this is what I've been trying to do too:

```
let localTimeZoneOffset = myTimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: Date());
let currentTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(- 
localTimeZoneOffset));
```

Still I could be at any area and I want to see if a store of another area is open hagin different timezones for both, the current time of the device and open-closed time of the store. My location could be anywhere and the store I pick too, so I think I would need to get the difference of both times or something like that

Let's supposed this is the info I got: Now = Date(); OpenTime = 2018-04-27 11:00:00 +0000; CloseTime = 2018-04-28 03:00:00 +0000; StoreTimeZone = "EST" With this info is it easy to get if the store is open or not if I am in a place with different timezone from the store? I already have the functions to compare is time is between the OpenTime and the CloseTime I just need to pass the correct time in the store to get if it is open or not right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - avoid using timezone abbreviations. Not all are unique (examples includes IST and CST).

Comment: @rmaddy yeah but that is how it is coming from the API, I cant change that, but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Dates do not have time zones. You can't get a `Date` that includes time zone information because `Date` does not depend on or include a time zone.

Comment: @TomHarrington in that case, I would need to add the difference of time for that timezone in order to get a similar time, right? How could I find the difference between currentDate UTC and the currentDate f the timezone I pass and add it currentDate?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Dates are completely independent of time zone. If you add time to a date, you get a later date.

Comment: It sounds like you need to convert the string from your api into a `Date` and then you can just compare that rather than trying to compare strings.

Comment: I am not trying to compare strings, I am trying to compare dates from different zones. For example I need to see if a store is open. I am at EST timezone and it's 11:30 pm so I see the schedule of a store that closes at 11 but the store is at PST which means that now it's 10pm in that zone and stills open. So I need to change my timezone to the store timezone to show a flag if it is open or close right now. Bud timezones can vary from many timezones @Paulw11

Comment: But as others have said, dates don't have timezone, they represent an absolute point in time. If you get data from an API that says the store closes at 22:00 in PST (assuming that means UTC-7) , you parse that to a `Date` (Which if you printed would show 05:00 utc, but again, there is no Timezone information in the `Date`) .  You then compare that against `Date.now` (which would show 03:30utc if you printed it to the console) and your comparison will tell you that the store is open.

Comment: Yeah, so what I am trying to do now is using  `TimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: Date());` and then `now.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-localTimeZoneOffset));` to add the difference necesary but the problem is  X1 time in X2 timeZone and Y1 time of Y2 timezone, could be of different areas always, is not a fixed value do the difference between times is not always the same. and the value Im getting from this operation is not the expected. @Paulw11

Comment: Just parse your string to a `Date` and you're done (with the caveat that Timezone abbreviations can be problematic as rmaddy pointed out). You can compare `Date`s without worrying about Timezones.  Try this in a playground `print(Date())`. It will show the time in UTC since that is the default for the debug description of a Date, but nowhere did you tell it to convert the Date to UTC because *`Date`s don't have time zones*

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data you are getting from the API. Does it include a day of the week, for example.  You don't need to worry about the "now"; you know when "now" is. You need to ensure that you are correctly parsing the data from your API into a `Date`

Comment: So you are  telling me to just use Date() to get my current date and compare it with the stores schedule?  I dont think this could help because my time is different from theirs and what I obtain from API are just SomeStore -> 1pm -11pm PST for example @Paulw11

Comment: I actually used the string only because that way I can obtain the time formatted for that timezone, otherwise i would prefer to dont have to parse my date, it actually comes as NSDate type @Paulw11

Comment: I am telling you to compare `Date()` with the `Date` that represents the store's schedule. If I parse "2018-04-28 08:23:00+1000" to a `Date`, I will get the same value as if I parse "2018-04-27 15:23:00-0700" since those two time strings represent the same point in time. Once you parse the string to a `Date` then you can ignore timezone. If you want to display the date then you can use a dateformatter to do so.  You may need to store the timezone for the store's hours somewhere so that you can format the `Date` for the relevant timezone, but don't try and store the timezone in the date itself

Comment: The `Date`s that represent a store's hours and the timezone that the store operates in are two separate, but related, pieces of information. To know whether a store is open or closed "now" you only need the `Date`. To display those hours in a meaningful way requires both pieces of information, but don't let the second requirement drive the way you meet the first.

Comment: @Paulw11 Here is an example of how time comes, then we just parse it to date and the value is correct, just shows exactly that time as `Date` type  but the problem when we need to  compare our time with theirs times in different zones.  **the api response for the time I will put it at the main description because is too long to post it here**

Comment: Show how you parse that data. You should end up with 7 instances of a struct that represent the hours for those days. The struct should have two `Date`s; one for opening and one for closing. You can then write a simple function in that struct that accepts a `Date` and returns `true` if the date >= opening and < closing. You will need to know the *store's timezone* to accurately create the opening and closing dates

Comment: This is when I print them in the console: 
start: 2018-04-27 11:00:00 +0000, end: 2018-04-28 03:00:00 +0000 @Paulw11 That is what I compare with my current date using this `if ([self compare:start] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;
    if ([self compare:end] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;
    return YES;` being self the NSDate class

Comment: Right; see that +0000; that indicates that (unless the store is in London) you haven't included the timezone when you parsed the `Date` from the string.

Comment: @Paulw11 Exactly, the timezone comes apart in another property and I have to parse it to TimeZone type by the abbr

Comment: @Paulw11Thank you so much for your response, but it is not working for me, please look at the comment I did after your solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution.  I have added a timezone to the JSON in a convenient place; you would need to adapt to allow for the location of the timezone in your data.

```
struct Schedule: Codable {
    var timezone: String
    var storeHours: [DayHours]
}

struct DayHours: Codable {
    var hours: String
    var day: String
    var date: String
}


struct OpeningHours {
    let day: String
    let openTime: Date
    let closeTime: Date

    func isOpen(on date: Date) -> Bool {
        return date >= openTime && date < closeTime
    }
}

struct StoreSchedule {
    let openingHours:[OpeningHours]
    let timezone: TimeZone

    init?(_ schedule: Schedule) {
        guard let timezone = TimeZone(abbreviation:schedule.timezone) else {
            return nil
        }

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = timezone
        self.timezone = timezone
        var openingHours = [OpeningHours]()
        for dayHours in schedule.storeHours {
            let components = dayHours.hours.components(separatedBy: "-")
            guard components.count == 2 else {
                return nil
            }
            let opening = components[0]
            let closing = components[1]
            guard let openTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(dayHours.date) \(opening)"),
                let closeTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(dayHours.date) \(closing)") else {
                    return nil
            }
            openingHours.append(OpeningHours(day: dayHours.day, openTime: openTime, closeTime: closeTime))
        }

        self.openingHours = openingHours
    }

    func isOpen(on date: Date) -> Bool{
        for openings in openingHours {
            if openings.isOpen(on: date) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

let json = """
{
"timezone": "PST",
"storeHours": [{
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Friday",
"date": "2018-04-27"
}, {
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Saturday",
"date": "2018-04-28"
}, {
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Sunday",
"date": "2018-04-29"
}, {
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Monday",
"date": "2018-04-30"
}, {
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Tuesday",
"date": "2018-05-01"
}, {
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Wednesday",
"date": "2018-05-02"
}, {
"hours": "7:00 AM - 11:00 PM",
"day": "Thursday",
"date": "2018-05-03"
}]
}
"""

let schedule = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)

if let storeSchedule = StoreSchedule(schedule) {
    //  print(storeSchedule)
    let openClosed = storeSchedule.isOpen(on: Date()) ? "Open":"Closed"
    print("Store is: \(openClosed)")
} else {
    print("Unable to create schedule")
}
```

> Store is: Open

Comment: I think this wont work because I need to work with what already is implemented in our project.
Let's supposed this is the info I got:
Now = Date();
OpenTime = 2018-04-27 11:00:00 +0000;
CloseTime = 2018-04-28 03:00:00 +0000;
StoreTimeZone = "EST"

With this info is it easy to get if the store is open or not if I am in a place with different timezone from the store? I already have the functions to compare is time is between the OpenTime and the CloseTime I just need to pass the correct time in the store to get if it is open or not right now

Comment: But what you have described is pretty much what my code does. It creates `Date`s that represent the open/close times and then looks to see if the store is open at the provided Date. No need to add time intervals or worry about time zones once you have created the Date. And if you want to know if the store is open "now" you don't care what timezone you are in

Comment: @keylinwu; I still don't understand what your issue is.